# Name of the algorithm used in ST_Distance function in PostGIS for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, gis, geospatial, postgis

I'm working with the PostGIS extension for PostgreSQL and using the ST_Distance function for calculating distances between two Points. I'm curious about the underlying algorithm that ST_Distance uses.

I have reviewed the official documentation for PostGIS and searched online for information about the algorithm used in ST_Distance. However, I couldn't find specific details about the algorithm. I expected to find information in the documentation, but it seems to be lacking in this regard. If anyone has insights or has encountered similar queries, please share your knowledge.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can look at the source code

Comment: While tangentially related this is not  specific programming issue. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the formula to calculate a euclidean distance on wikipedia: [euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), under "two dimension".

If you follow the path through the PostGIS source code starting from ST_distance, you end up at the function [lw_dist2d_pt_pt](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/03e8bc97e2015d466aee4b15819c9f65e781e68e/liblwgeom/measures.c#L2365) that implements the formula above.